# What happens if you multiply a point with its order on complete Edwards curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I was recently working with some ECC crypto and stumbled across the following phrase [on the SafeCurves page](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/equation.html):

> The **rational points** of a complete Edwards curve are the pairs (x,y) of
>   elements of F_p satisfying the equation; there is no extra "point at
>   infinity".

Normally, if you have a point $G$ on a curve $E$ with order (of the point) $q$, multiplying $qG=0G=\mathcal O$ results in the point at infinity.

But apparently complete Edwards curves don't have said extra point.

**So what happens in this case?**

Comment: I consider this related to cryptography as ECC is a core discipline of cryptography and multiplying the order with the point is a common self-test for libraries. Furthermore wrong handling of this case may lead to implementation based (side-channel?) attacks. That being said, if there is consensus for migration, I think Math.SE would be the appropriate target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually multiplying an elliptic curve point $G$ by its order $q$ gets you to the neutral element of the group, i.e., the point $O$ such that $P+O=P$ for any point P.

In a generic elliptic curves this point is the point at infinity $O$. However on Edwards curves, this point is $(0,1)$, i.e., it can be represented by affine coordinates. This is also stated on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve#Edwards_addition_law).

Therefore, multiplying a point by its order, on an Edwards curve, gets you the point $(0,1)$

This means that on Edwards curves: $P+(0,1)=P$ for any point $P$.