# ECC encryption in practice

Tags: public-key

I'd like to encrypt a message using PGP keys, and elliptic curve cryptography as the method.

In practice, using the Erlang `:crypto` module, but first, I'd like to wrap my head around how I would begin to go about this.

Should I generate an ECC PGP key?
Should I use my normal PGP key and sign using `:crypto` module using ECC as the method.. if that is possible that is.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

First time poster in Cryptography, BTW.

Comment: related [How does encryption work in elliptic curve cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31602/18298),

Answer (score 1):

The programming aspect of this question should be asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), but I suppose you can figure it out all on your own.

Yes, you need to generate ECC keypair if you want to use ECC algorithms. Every type of public-key cryptography suite require specifying algorithms, if your PGP keys are already using ECC algorithms (ECDH, ECIES, ECDSA), then you may reuse those depending on software support as not all libraries and apps support all formats (there are SSH, PKCS-PEM, PGP formats from what I know).

Also note that you should generate different keys for different purpose - don't reuse encryption key for digital signature and vice-versa.